# Change Formatting if cell is in a range

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is when a cell (A1) matches something in a named range ("Names")  then it changes colour, however if it doesn't but matches something a different named range ("Eye") then it becomes a different colour (there are many more ranges, but I'm sure I'll be able to figure it out after I have two working)

Things to note:

I know this can be done with conditional formatting, however due to the number of named ranges, and sizes of the ranges I was hoping it would be easier using a macro.

I so far have managed to get it working for one named range, and when A1 isn't a formula (however A1 will be)

My 2 lots of code so far are (note this is under sheet1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Application.Run ("Colour")
    End If

End Sub
```

The my second one (is being a seperate module):

```
Sub Colour()

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each c In .Range("Names").Cells

        If c.Value = .Range("A1").Value Then
            Range("A1").Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Color = 5287936
            End With
        End If

        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    ApplyColor Me.Range("A1")
End If
End Sub

Sub ApplyColor(ValueRange As Range)
Dim MatchRanges As Variant
Dim MatchColors As Variant
Dim MatchValue As Variant
Dim i As Long

MatchRanges = Array("Names", "Eye")
MatchColors = Array(5287936, 4287952)
MatchValue = ValueRange.Value

ValueRange.Interior.Color = vbWhite
For i = LBound(MatchRanges) To UBound(MatchRanges)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Range(MatchRanges(i)), MatchValue) > 0 Then
        ValueRange.Interior.Color = MatchColors(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

A couple of notes: "Color" is a VBA reserved word and could cause issues, so I used something else for your sub name. You don't need to use `Application.Run` in this situation, just the sub's name and its arguments (or `Call` if you prefer).

Comment: Didn't like your Me in Me.Range in line 18. So I changed that to Worksheets("sheet1").Range and it now works fine. Thanks for your help :D